# How do I handle C++ dependencies that conflict on a type name?

Tags: c++, macos, build, clang

I'm running CI on a project on linux and macOS. This project depends on Google's V8 and the Cairo graphics library. Recently, the macOS builds have started failing because apparently on macOS, Cairo includes some mac header that defines `Boolean`. However, V8 also defines a `Boolean` type. How would I solve this kind of issue?

https://travis-ci.org/github/romgrk/node-gtk/jobs/736552109

Comment: Have you tried wrapping one of the libraries in a namespace?

Comment: V8 is already namespaced. And the other isn't acutally the library, the library is just pulling a macOS-defined header.

Answer (score 1):

If the Boolean is a MACRO in one of these two libraries then you can strategically undefine/refefine the MACRO upon inclusion of headers. If it is a type/alias/class/struct in both cases then it is more complex.

If the definitions match then this shouldn't be a problem otherwise this is an ODR (one definition rule) issue and according to C++ standart violating it is strictly forbidden. So you need a work around.

Simplest and most reliable method is to rename all `Boolean` of one kind to something else. If you work with external library you cannot modify then submit bug report. Other option is to link to the libraries as shared libraries so the Boolean is never defined twice in your code (hopefully Boolean isn't an exported type and used internally only).

Comment: Thanks! Boolean is exported for V8, but for Cairo it's included from macOS files :/ (see https://travis-ci.org/github/romgrk/node-gtk/jobs/736552109#L6350-L6358 ). Would you be able to provide a bit more details on what you mean by link as a shared library? I would have thought that I'm already linking to a shared library.

Comment: @RomGrk there are shared (dll/so) and static (lib/a) libraries. Static libraries expose all their symbols while shared/dynamic libraries expose only the symbols that they choose to at price of some other complexity (like having their own separate heap/dynamic memory and some other things). If Cairo is built as dynamic/shared library and doesn't leak `Boolean` outside nor imports from V8 then you can make it work.